# send html email with link ..click on link will open html email as web page

Tags: java, email

I have a requirement where i need to send html email with link 'open email as webpage'.on click of this link the content of email will be open in browser .

Please help me how to implement this using java.
i am able to send html email.

Answer (score 0):

In link add some `parameters` to recognize who'm clicking  and call some servlet with those params.In servlet dispatch the appropriate `webpage.`